# OAuth2 Library Yields Property Storage Quota Error

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, storage, libraries, quota

I have a script using [Google's OAuth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2), which recently started to fail with the error

> You have exceeded the property storage quota. Please remove some properties and try again.

I inspected the properties and did not find any unexpected differences from my original configuration. The full stringified text length of my properties is around 5000 characters, which is well below the [500kB/property store quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) and the longest individual property ~2500 characters (below the 9kB/value quota).

I've discovered that this error only occurs when I use [Google's OAuth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) with a service account. However, ***if I include the [library dist](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/dist/OAuth2.gs) directly in my project, the error disappears.***

Why is there a difference in how the properties service behaves between the library and the local copy if they appear to be the same versions?

(In other scripts where I use the OAuth2 library with a standard authorization code grant flow, I have no issues.)

This script will replicate the error, but requires that you [create a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount) and set the correct script properties as defined in `getAdminDirectory_()`. (Using Rhino interpreter.)

```
/**
 * Get a GSuite User.
 */
function getUser() {
  var email = "name@exampledomain.com";
  var user = AdminDirectory_getUser_(email);
  Logger.log(user);
}

/**
 * Gets a user from the GSuite organization by their email address.
 * @returns {User} - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource
 */
function AdminDirectory_getUser_(email) {
  var service = getAdminDirectory_();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/" + email;
    var options = {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken()
      }
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    return result;
  } else {
    throw service.getLastError();
  }
}

/**
 * Configures the service.
 */
function getAdminDirectory_() {
  // Get service account from properties
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var serviceAccount = JSON.parse(scriptProperties.getProperty("service_account"));
  
  // Email address of the user to impersonate.
  var user_email = scriptProperties.getProperty("service_account_user");
  
  return OAuth2.createService("AdminDirectory:" + user_email)
  // Set the endpoint URL.
  .setTokenUrl("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token")
  
  // Set the private key and issuer.
  .setPrivateKey(serviceAccount.private_key)
  .setIssuer(serviceAccount.client_email)
  
  // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
  // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
  // delegation:
  // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
  .setSubject(user_email)
  
  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(scriptProperties)
  
  // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
  // setup of domain-wide delegation.
  .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue. Consider adding a star(on top left) to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168665909)  to let Google developers know that you're affected. Consider adding a comment to the tracker with details requested from [#7](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168665909#comment7)

#### Possible solutions:

- As said in the question, directly use the [library code by copy pasting](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/dist/OAuth2.gs) instead of using the buggy library feature.
- Switch to v8-[#21](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168665909#comment21)
- Wait for random/Auto resolution -[#14](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168665909#comment14)